# NSUInteger C Array

Tags: objective-c, c, arrays

I ran across this presentation when searching Google for TDD principles

http://qualitycoding.org/files/BowlingGame-ObjectiveC.pdf

There's something I'm not familiar with in it. There's a declaration like this:

```
NSUInteger _rolls[21];
NSUInteger _currentRoll;
```

From following the code I've found that _rolls is an array containing several uints. But I have never seen this. Is this a part of C?

I would be more familiar with

```
NSArray *rolls;
NSUInteger aRoll = rolls[index];
```

Is the [21] describing the count, or the max limit for this array?

Comment: "Is this a part of C?" YES (`_rolls`)! In case of `NSArray *rolls;` you have Objective C array so `rolls[index]` is in fact invocation of `[rolls objectAtIndex: index];`.

Comment: Here's the blog post for that file. Feel free to ask questions there. http://qualitycoding.org/tdd-kata/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NSUInteger _rolls[21];` is declaring a C array of `NSUInteger` types with a size of 21, not an `NSArray`.

Think about how you would declare an array in C:

```
type arrayName [ arraySize ];
```

With ints:

```
int rolls[5] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
```

It works the same way.

The number in the brackets is the size of the array, the maximum number of values it can hold.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, an `NSArray` cannot contain `NSUInteger`, you can only put objects in an Objective-C array.

If you want to store `NSUInteger`s in an array, you'll have to wrap them first:

```
NSArray *rolls = [NSArray arrayWithObject: @(17)];
NSUInteger aRoll = rolls[0].unsignedIntegerValue;
```

Or, you can use a C array like the one you saw in the PDF...